# How Can I Send an HTTP Request In a File?

Tags: security, http, http-get, netcat

I am learning about computer security and have a question about commands.  I have a vulnerable web server that I can exploit a buffer overflow in by using the telnet command and and then sending a http get with a super long URL.  The URL will overflow a buffer.  I know that works for sure.  But now, I want to use netcat to automate the process.  So far, I have

```
netcat localhost 8080 < payload1
```

I send it to the localhost because I am running the server and the attack on the same computer.  Payload1 is currently the malformed HTTP Get statement.  However, the server cannot understand this because it cannot open the file to see the HTTP Get statement.  Therefore, my question is: how can I make the HTTP Get statement executable, or how can I get the server to recognize the HTTP Get within the file?

Thanks!

edit:
it seems like the req which holds the uri, among other things, is 0.  Or at least it is when I check it with GDB.  This is the line of the code that is giving me a problem:

```
  if (req->uri == NULL || req->method == NULL ||
      req->headers == NULL || req->version == NULL) {
          return 0;
  }
```

GDB says its a segmentation fault here at the if statement.

I know it probably doesn't mean much since the rest of the code from the server isn't there.  However, the file that the netcat statement sends is :

```
get /aaaaaaaaaaaaAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa http/1.1
```

If I were to use telnet to transmit it, the server does crash so I know its a problem with netcat.  There was a statement that said payload1 needed to be in DOS format with CRLF end lines.  To check this I transfered the file to a windows machine and it displayed properly however I was wondering if there was another way to check this?

Answer (score 0):

What error do you see that makes you think the server can't read the file? With the command line you've used, the "server" doesn't read the file, your OS shell opens the file and uses that as the standard input for the netcat process.

So I'd ask you to:

1. Check the path of payload1. You may need to use something like `nc localhost 8080 < /path/to/payload1`
2. Check that your server is listening on TCP port 8080
3. If none of these work, put up some error messages / symptoms of problems you're seeing

**Update (based on question edit):**

The *client* here is netcat. Based on your edit, it seems like the *server* is crashing. So the request is going through to the server. Its possible you just discovered another bug with the server software (in addition to the original buffer overflow). When you tried using telnet, did you send an indentical URI?

Comment: yes, the command is exactly the same get command that I used using telnet.  That is what makes it so weird.